# Round down results on laravel query

Tags: laravel

Hey guys I´ve got a simple question, I'm doing some math operations on a selectRaw query, but i need to round down the results (for example with floor()). How can I do this on my selectRaw query?

```
            $primer =  DB::connection('lab_inv')
          ->table('products')
          ->join('primer_adaptor', 'products.id', 'primer_adaptor.Product_id')
          ->selectraw('primer_adaptor.Product_id, primer_adaptor.Primer_Name,
    primer_adaptor.Amount / primer_adaptor.Amount_Run AS Amount,
    products.Amount / (products.Amount_Run * products.Runs_week) AS Runs, (products.Runs / products.Runs_week) * 5 AS Running_days')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your may just use MySQL's `FLOOR` function as you typically would in a raw MySQL query, e.g.

```
$sql = "pa.Product_id, pa.Primer_Name, pa.Amount / pa.Amount_Run AS Amount, ";
$sql .= "FLOOR(p.Amount / (p.Amount_Run * p.Runs_week)) AS Runs, ";
$sql .= "(products.Runs / products.Runs_week) * 5 AS Running_days";
$primer =  DB::connection('lab_inv')
    ->table('products AS p')
    ->join('primer_adaptor AS pa', 'p.id', 'pa.Product_id')
    ->selectraw($sql)
    ->get();
```

Here I have just taken the floor of the alias you named "Runs," but you may use `FLOOR` wherever you want.